# AJAX Loader/Progress Bar for Flash File

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, actionscript

I want to implement a progress par using AJAX for a flash file.

Please see the demo here

http://www.freeplaynow.com/online-games/play/1729/park-my-plane.html

Tried to debug their page but the javascript is obfuscated and im not so good in js. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want this in JavaScript or in Flash?

Comment: I want it in javascript.. That prograssbar is generic i.e it works based on filesize of embedded flash content / downloaded content. But I dont know how.

Comment: I could be wrong, as I'm not a Flash expert (to be frank, not at all), but IIRC those progress bars are made in Flash, not in Javascript.

Comment: Yeah no problem buddy.. But these are done in javascript. I dont know how.. 

The most I was able to find was that the flash files is sent using 206 Header so I guess the javascript is fed with original filesize of swf file. At at each interval it finds out what amount of data is downloaded so far.

But practically I dont know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like an [AJAX progress bar](http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/)?

Comment: no this works through PHP. I know this technique. What I am looking is a progress bar that is based upon how much of the flash content is loaded.